Generating an email with an inline text link in it via AppleScript
I'm generating emails (without automatically sending them) with the following AppleScript and would like to replace the long_ugly_url with a text link in the email, but not sure how.
set theList to {{name:"John", email:"john@example.org", address:"Street Address, Pensacola, FL 32505"}, {name:"Janice", email:"Janice@example.org", address:"Street Address, New York, NY 10019"}--etc}

set theSubject to "This still a good mailing address?"

repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    set cur to item a of theList
    set theBody to "Hey " & name of cur & ", blablabla" & return & "long_ugly_url"

    set theAddress to email of cur
    
    tell application "Mail"
        set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {sender:"Me <mike@example.com>", subject:theSubject, content:theBody & return & return, visible:true}
        tell theNewMessage
            set visibile to true
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theAddress}
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat

Suggestions, direction?
Thanks much.

Where does long_ugly_url come from and what does it look like? Is it unique per e-mail?

it's just a static email link string. (a link to a SendGrid signup form)

You could append the link as plain text – most e-mail clients will automatically make the link clickable. Do you want to send a HTML body in your e-mail and be able to change the link's text? Does Applescript - sending html email in Mail.app help?

So when I, in OSX mail, highlight some text and CMD-K is it simply generating a simple HTML link?

Edit (menu) > Add Link… (cmd+k) also converts the e-mail body from plain text to HTML. The conversion is only needed if you want formatting or inline links with link text that does not match the link URL.

Plain Text
A link can be embedded within the plain text contents of the e-mail body. The recipient's e-mail client should automatically detect the link:
set theList to {{name:"John", email:"john@example.org", address:"Street Address, Pensacola, FL 32505"}}

set theSubject to "This still a good mailing address?"
set theURL to "https://example.com/join"

repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    set cur to item a of theList
    set theBody to "Hey " & name of cur & ", blablabla" & return & theURL
    set theAddress to email of cur
    
    tell application "Mail"
        set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {sender:"Me <mike@example.com>", subject:theSubject, content:theBody & return & return, visible:true}
        tell theNewMessage
            set visibile to true
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theAddress}
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat

If the long URL is a problem, a link shortener may be an easy solution.
If you need an HTML body to the e-mail, see Applescript - sending html email in Mail.app
